# React Context Error - Cannot destructure property ' ' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

When I am trying to access the context for team in the following code, I get the following error:

Cannot destructure property 'team' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
at Team (./app/components/Select/Team.tsx:15:13)
at stringify ()

What could be the issue here?

Here is my Team.tsx component

```
const Team: FC<Props> = ({values}) => { 
    
    const {team, setTeam} = useContext(TeamContext)
    
    const onValueChange = useCallback((team: string) => setTeam(team),[setTeam])
    
    return (
        <Select
            defaultValue={DEFAULT_TEAM}
            value={team}
            onValueChange={onValueChange}
        >
            <SelectTrigger>
                <SelectValue placeholder="Select a team" />
            </SelectTrigger>
            <SelectContent>
                <SelectLabel> Team </SelectLabel>
                {
                    values.map((team) => (
                        <SelectItem key={team} value={team}>
                            {team}
                        </SelectItem>
                    ))
                }
            </SelectContent>
        </Select>
    )
```

And here is where I create my context:

```
'use client'

import {createContext, useState } from 'react'
import type {Dispatch, SetStateAction, PropsWithChildren} from 'react'


type TeamContextType = {
    team: string,
    setTeam: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}

export const DEFAULT_TEAM = 'Arsenal'

const TeamContext = createContext<TeamContextType>({
    team: DEFAULT_TEAM,
    setTeam: () => {

    },
})

export const TeamContextProvider = ({children}: PropsWithChildren) => { 
    const [team, setTeam] = useState<string>(DEFAULT_TEAM)

    return (
        <TeamContext.Provider value={{team, setTeam}}>
            {children}
        </TeamContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default TeamContext;
```

in my Team.tsx I have added useContext to include the team context but it is still not working. What could be th

Answer (score 1):

I was missing 'use client' in my client select component which was the reason why the context was showing as undefined